What is the probability of condition rating 5 following a given condition rating?
I have an asset management system in which assets are given a condition rating from 1 (good) to 5 (bad). Assets are inspected and given a rating every year; new assets start with condition rating 1 and deteriorate over time, until they have a rating of 5.
I would  like to understand the probability of an asset with a given rating getting a rating of 5 the next year. My questions are: do I have enough information to estimate this? If not, what more information or assumptions do I need to be able to estimate this?
I have recorded data showing how assets deteriorate over time (figure 1).

Figure 1. Graph showing how condition rating changes from 1 to 5 for different deterioration rates.
If I assume a distribution of deterioration rates, I can estimate what proportion of assets have each condition rating for a given age (figure 2).

Figure 2. Asset condition grade probability over time.
